# Java: How to turn a string into a int

Tags: java, string, integer

I just recently started coding with Java (one week).

I want to write a program that ends when I type 'e' into the console. However when I type 'e' I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

Can you help me understand what's going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
    void top() {

    String e = "0";
    int i=Integer.parseInt(e);
    
    int alternierendeSumme = 0;
    int eingegebeneZahl = eingabeZahl("Geben Sie eine ganze Zahl ein. 0 = Abbrechen.");
    int counter = 0;
    
    //Integer intobject = new Integer(0);
    //int e = intobject.intValue();
    
    while(eingegebeneZahl != i) {
        
        eingegebeneZahl = eingabeZahl("Geben Sie eine ganze Zahl ein. 0 = Abbrechen.");
        counter = counter + 1;

             if ((counter % 2) == 0) {
                 alternierendeSumme = alternierendeSumme - eingegebeneZahl;
             } else { alternierendeSumme = alternierendeSumme + eingegebeneZahl;
             }              
    }
        
System.out.println("Die alternierende Summe beträgt [" + alternierendeSumme + "]"); 

}       

void print(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int eingabeZahl(String text) {
    print(text);                                                
    return sc.nextInt();
}

String eingabeZahl() {
    return sc.next().toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't understand the problem. Integer.parseInt can turn a string into an int, you have that in your code. so where are you getting the input from the user? This is where you need to check if the input is 'e' or something else.

Comment: How would turning a string into an integer help you determine if a user enters the value "e"?  I'm afraid it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Please show the code of your method `eingabeZahl(String)`.

Comment: _I could do this with a break() but i have learned that you shouldnt do that_ - well, unlearn that. There's nothing wrong with break, whomever told you this is probably just selling hot air. _But isnt working like i want._ I suggest you edit this question and elaborate a bit on what you do want :)

Comment: @JPMoresmau i just added the missing code, the thing is once i type e into the console i just get an error

Comment: @rex_power_colter: *"once i type e into the console i just get an error"* - What error do you get and what line throws that error?  The error is telling you what's wrong, it's best not to ignore it.

Comment: `String e = "0";
    int i=Integer.parseInt(e);` - just type `int i = 0;`, or even simpler, forget `i`, forget `e`; all you want is `if (eingegebeneZahl != 0)`. You're making this way more complicated than you think it is.

Comment: @David line 7 and 39 i also get a error from the scanner (
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source))

Comment: you cannot enter 'e' because that's not a number and you are reading with parseInt. You need to enter '0' as your own intstruction text mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is working fine, although I do have some suggestions (see below)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    // changed local variables to fields to reduce method arguments
    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int alternatingSum;
    private int counter;

    private void top() {
        alternatingSum = 0;
        counter = 1;
        // counter > 0 is a loop invariant, used here to iterate 'forever'
        // while(true) also works
        while (counter > 0) {
            System.out.println("Geben Sie eine ganze Zahl ein. 0 = Abbrechen.");
            int entry = scanner.nextInt();
            if (entry == 0) {
                // in this case using a break reflects the real process of 
                // data entry until a special value is entered 
                // so I don't see why not
                break;
            }
            // because counter and alternatingSum are fields now, we only need
            // to pass the entry
            updateAlternatingSum(entry);

            // it's usually a good idea to update the counter at the end of the loop
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        System.out.printf("Die alternierende Summe beträgt [%s]%n", alternatingSum);
    }

    private void updateAlternatingSum(int eingegebeneZahl) {
        // the first entry has an odd counter (1) so the number will be added to alternierendeSumme
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            alternatingSum = alternatingSum - eingegebeneZahl;
        }
        else {
            alternatingSum = alternatingSum + eingegebeneZahl;
        }
    }

    // added a main method in order to run the code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.top();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to convert the string "0" to a number 0? It would be much simpler to do something like

```
while(input != 0){
    exit program
}
```

that way you're not having to convert a string to an int and it simplifies your code slightly